# Comparing properties of objects that equal through an id

Tags: java, unique, equality

Lets assume there is a data service that returns instances of the class `cat`:

```
class Cat {
  int id;
  String name;
  int iq;
}
```

I want to hold the instances inside a `Set<Cat>` that must not hold two cats with the same id. So I need to override the `equals` and `hashcode` method to only check for the `id`.

My question is how can I detect if a cat inside my set requires an update when I receive a new instance from the service with the same id, but different values for `name` and/or `iq`? I cannot add the properties to `equals` or `hashcode` since then it would be possible that the Set holds instances of the same id.

Do I have to compare all the fields manually or is there another Java-typical solution for this?

---

Edit for clarification:

Just updating the `Set` with the new instance would not be enough because there is code triggered on an update. So what I want to do is:

```
if (set.contains(newCat)) {
  Cat current = set.get(newCat);
  if (!current.equals(newCat)) { //obviously this is not enough
    set.add(current);
    //notify EventBusses and such
  }
}
```

Solutions that came into my mind are:

1. `current.requiresUpdate(newCat) //basically copy of equals() with properties`
2. `current.updateWith(newCat) //same as above but keeping the old instance`
3. `if (!current.name.euqals(newCat.name)) //for each property`
4. only get the objects from the service that have changed. Optimal, but out of scope for me.

All of which would require somewhat redundant code which is why I was hoping there is a pattern or collection that does the work for me.

The solution can include Guava classes.

Comment: Do you really want the set not to hold two cats with the same ID, or do you actually want no two cats to have the same ID? If it's the former, use a `Map<Integer, Cat>`, and check if `map.containsKey(id)` before adding it.

Comment: You could hold all the instances inside a `Map<Integer, Cat>` instead of a `Set<Cat>`. Then you can still have your `equals()` method check the cats are identical. Or just write a different method that compares all the fields. Effectively you have to do that anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two distinct problems:

- **Comparing `Cat` objects**: If two `Cat` objects are equal only if `id`, `name` and `iq` are equal, than implement the `equals` method accordingly.
- **Maintaining a collection of `Cat` objects**: To maintain a collection of `Cat` objects in which there are no two objects with the same `id`, use a `Map<Integer, Cat>` as already suggested.

Your code may then look something like:

```
if (mapOfCats.contains(newCat.id)) {
  Cat current = mapOfCats.get(newCat.id);
  if (!current.equals(newCat)) {
    mapOfCats.put(newCat.id, newCat);
    // notify EventBusses and such
  }
}
```

Comment: I've accepted your answer since its the Java way to do things. For android developers with the same problem have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.html. In the end this class solved all my problems.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to insert the value again.

If id will be match from previous cat object, it will be overwritten in set.

A HashSet internally maintains a HashMap to identify duplicates.

Comment: My question was not specific enough. I've updated it to show that a simple update is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler solution is: if found equal - remove it and add again, with updated values. The code can be somewhat like this :

```
yourSet.remove(cat);
yourSet.add(newCatObejectWithSameID);
```

`newCatObejectWithSameID` will have different `name` and `iq`.

Comment: My question was not specific enough. I've updated it to show that a simple update is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements sound slightly strange - if the ID field is supposed to uniquely identify a `Cat`, then there should surely only ever be a single instance of a `Cat` with that ID. Or, at least, the corresponding fields on the multiple `Cat` instances should be equal.

However, assuming there *can* be multiple logically different `Cat` instances with the same ID, the easiest way to handle this is to use a `Map<Integer, Cat>`:

```
Map<Integer, Cat> cats = new HashMap<>();
for (Cat cat : getAllCats()) {
  if (!cats.containsKey(cat.id)) {
    cats.put(cat.id, cat);
  } else {
    // Do whatever - ignore, log a message, throw an exception?
  }
}
Collection<Cat> catsWithUniqueIds = cats.values();
```

Comment: I think the question states something like "there's an instance in the set, I get an updated back from (somewhere), how do I determine if I need to update it". Which is trivially answerable by just replacing it. A set seems fine for this, except for its lack of a `replace` or add that just adds it :/

Comment: My question was not specific enough. I've updated it to show that a simple update is not enough.